# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvjoy'

Tags: python

I am currently trying to install a python module named "pyvjoy" (https://github.com/tidzo/pyvjoy) but I run into an error after importing

here's the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "runner.py", line 5, in 
>       import PlayHelper
>     File "C:\Users\Slay\Desktop\RLBot-master\PlayHelper.py", line 1, in 
>       import pyvjoy
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvjoy'

I have tried to install it via copying the library to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages but no luck

Comment: To copy the code is not the adequate way to install a package. You need to have the code where your own code is, or install it correctly. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be using a package manager instead of manually managing every package. Corollary: never use peoples code that isnt on pipy or conda, it means they havent gone through the effort to publish it and dont really expect anyone to use it.

2) You might like pygame or Tkinter for getting joystick input. Mature libraries that have been around for a while are almost always better then some dudes github project with 13 commits.